# Insert [$_POST] var into DOM search string?

Tags: php, simplexml, nodes

I'm not sure if I named that title correctly, but basically I have a variable from a $_POST (a name of a band) and I want to insert it in place of a node's name in a line like this-

```
$lastvisits = $address->$band->getElementsByTagName("lastvisit");
```

where `$band` is

```
$band = $_POST['band']
```

because the node inside of $address could be any name really, and might not exist.
I'm sure there must be a simple way, but I'm not sure of the formatting.

If it exists or it doesn't, $lastvisits = $address->$band>getElementsByTagName("lastvisit") brings an error- **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in...

The XML-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addresses>
<address>
    <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
    <Beatles>
        <lastvisit>12/08/2006</lastvisit>
    </Beatles>
</address>
    <address>
    <ip>125.0.0.1</ip>
</address>
 </addresses>
```

This is the full code:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("votingxml/addresses.xml");
$addresses = $doc->getElementsByTagName("address");
$band = strval($_POST['band']);
$pVoted = false;
$pFound = false;

//Loop through the addresses nodes and see if the person has voted before for each( $addresses as $address )
{

$ips = $address->getElementsByTagName("ip");
            $ip = $ips->item(0)->nodeValue;
                            if ($ip == $domain){

                $pFound = true;             
            if ($address->$band == 'NULL'){
                 $bandfound= false;
                 $newBandElement = $doc->createElement($_POST['band']);
                 $newLastVisitElement = $doc->createElement('lastvisit');
                 $dayvalue = $doc->createTextNode($today);
                 $dayvalue = $newLastVisitElement->appendChild($dayvalue);

                 $newBandElement->appendChild($newLastVisitElement);
                 $address->appendChild($newBandElement);
                 $doc->save("votingxml/addresses.xml");
                 $pVoted = false;
            }
            else{

                 $bandfound =true;
                                 $lastvisits = $address->$band->getElementsByTagName("lastvisit");
                 $lastvisit = $lastvisits->item(0)->nodeValue;

                 if ($lastvisit == $today){
                        echo "alreadyvoted";
                        $pVoted = true;
                     }else{
                    $lastvisits->item(0)->nodeValue = $today;
                    $doc->save("votingxml/addresses.xml");
                    $pVoted = false;
                     }

            }
        }
        else if ($ip != $domain)
        {
            $pFound = false;
        }
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That somehow smells like an xml file being used as a database. If that's what you do: Better us a real database like MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite. If you need XML output simply build it on the fly or after a change.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit #1**: Looks like you're referring to DOM in your added example, not SimpleXML.  Still, here's how you do it with SimpleXML objects using your XML structure...

```
$band = $_POST['band'];

if (property_exists($address, $band)) {
    $lastvisits = $address->$band->lastvisit;
}
else {
    /* handle the fact that the name of the element which the user passed is invalid */
}
```

Note: there's only 1 lastvisit element.  If there are to be more, you'll need to wrap those lastvisit elements into a single "lastvisits" parent element within the XML file.  Valid XML and all that.

**Edit #2**: there are some problems with your xml structure.  "Beatles" is way too unique to be the name of an element.  You may want to change it up like so:

```
<addresses>
   <address>
      <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
      <visits>
         <visit>
            <band>Beatles</band>
            <lastvisit>12/08/2006</lastvisit>
         </visit>
         <visit>
            <band>New Kids On the Block</band>
            <lastvisit>1/14/2008</lastvisit>
         </visit>
      </visits>
   </address>
   <address>
      <ip>24.135.9.2</ip>
      <visits>
...
      </visits>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

Then you'll want to search for the `ip` node with value of the IP you want to search for, then under that for a `band` node for the value "Beatles".

**Edit #3, 4:** Adding method for DOM using DOMXPath class to run searches on the above XML structure, and add new record if band not found...

```
$band = $_POST['band'];
$client_IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("votingxml/addresses.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$ip_query = $xpath->query('//addresses/address/ip[. = "' . $client_IP . '"]');
if ($ip_query->length === 1) {
    // client's IP found, now grab and work with the client's address record
    $address = $ip_query->item(0)->parentNode;
    // search for the visit record within $address for band element value = $band
    $band_query = $xpath->query('visits/visit/band[. = "'.$band.'"]', $address);
    if ($band_query->length === 1) {
        // $band found, now get visit parent record for more details
        $visit = $band_query->item(0)->parentNode;
        // with that, now do something with the record's lastvisit value
        echo $visit->getElementsByTagName("lastvisit")->item(0)->nodeValue;
        }
    else {
        // $band not found.  Add new visit record to the XML file
        // point to 'visits' group element
        $visits = $address->getElementsByTagName("visits")->item(0);
        // create a new 'visit' element, complete with 'band' and 'lastvisit' child elements
        $visit = $doc->createElement("visit");
        $band = $doc->createElement("band", $band);
        $lastvisit = $doc->createElement("lastvisit", date("n/d/Y"));
        $visit->appendChild($band);
        $visit->appendChild($lastvisit);
        // now add new 'visit' element to 'visits' element and save
        $visits->appendChild($visit);
        $doc->save("votingxml/addresses.xml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're right, at some point I switched from simplexml to DOM. Would this not work for DOM as well? Because at this point, it's acting as if the property doesn't exist everytime, even if it does. And there aren't to be more than one lastvisit inside each band element- the date gets overwritten when updated.

Comment: I don't care if it works or not, I just like that New Kids on the Block made it into this discussion. OK, this will be a pain in the ass to change, but you're right, that makes more sense. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, `property_exists` won't work on DOM like that.  In SimpleXML, the child element basically _is_ a property.  In DOM, you'll have to do searches or use the `getElementByTagName($band)` method (assuming your example).  That will return a `DOMNodeList` object.  If the band "Beatles" doesn't exist, that `DOMNodeList`'s object `length` property will be 0.

Comment: I still have a problem with this- originally, the point of the script was to look for the band, and if it existed, check the band's 'lastvisit'. With this new setup, once I find the band, I can't directly access the 'lastvisit'. I would need to look through each vist, find the band, and then go back to its parent visit, and then get the 'lastvisited'. I'm not sure how to do it.    $allvisits = $doc->getElementsByTagName("visit");
  foreach( $allvisits as $eachvisit ){
          
      if ($eachvisit->band==$band) {... and then $lastvisits = $eachvisit->getElementsByTagName("lastvisit"); ?

Comment: @Brian Williams: you can use the `DOMXPath` class to run searches.  DOM example added.

Comment: Once again, you are a life-saver. I'm almost there, I have one last issue, and it stems, I think, from my lack of understanding exctly how xpath works- if the band doesn't exist, I need to go back two dir to 'visits' (the same one that also holds the 'ip' node) and create a new 'visit' folder. I've tried:  $query3 = $xpath->query('//visits[. = "visits"]', $address);
and then $newVisitElement = $query3->appendChild($newVisitElement); but that doesn't work. What would the correct xpath code be for this?

Comment: @Brian Williams: `$xpath->query('//visits[. = "visits"]'` returns a node list of all elements with the "visits" tag containing the text "visits"... meaning none of them.

Comment: @Brian Williams: If `$query->length === 1` under the _$band_ part returns false (sorry, should've not reused $query variable to make a clearer distinction there), this means the band name which client supplied wasn't found.  In that `else` case, you'll need to insert a new child element under `visits` under the $address element.  Throw in another `$something = $address->getElementsByTagName("visits")->item(0)` to get the "visits" group, draw up a new "visit" element complete with band and lastvisit child elements, then `$something->appendChild($you_new_visit_element)`.  Then `save`.

Comment: @Brian Williams: In fact, if you know Javascript DOM functions (strictly IE and Firefox cross-compatible methods), it's kind of exactly the same way.

Comment: $something = $address->getElementsByTagName("visits")->item(0);
$newVisitElement = $doc->createElement('visit');
$something->appendChild($newVisitElement);    This third line is returning an error of "Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in...Line 46"

Comment: @Brian Williams: give me a sec on this one.  `$address` is actually now a `DOMNode` object, which doesn't actually have a `getElementsByTagName()` method according to documentation... which should've given a `method not found` error... but it doesn't.

Comment: @Brian Williams: sorry, long night. I had you working with `$address` as pointing to the wrong child node. Should be `$address = $ip_query->item(0)->parentNode;`. I also had you doing the wrong xpath query which didn't restrict the `$band` search to `$adress` child elements.  I've updated my example to clarify some things and insert the new band record if not found.  Regardless, keep digging through DOM documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and more test cases to make sure everything's all good.

Comment: Thanks so much again, I should hopefully be able to take it from here, thats awesome that you can take the time to help out a stranger, I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: I'm so happy, its finally working, I'm gonna to cry. Or maybe just go get drunk. Thank you!

Comment: @Brian Williams: you're welcome.  I actually learned something.  I was about to submit a new PHP bug since `$address = $ip_query->item(0)` was giving the wrong class from what I expected.  This means a world of difference in what you're able to do with an XML structure.  Turns out I was doing it wrong (see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42451).  Yes, DOM is a juggling act of several PHP classes.